# Having more than one React application

Tags: reactjs

After executing the commands shown in the React installation tutorial I got on with my React project. Considering that in a React folder there can be a single file where the application will be loaded does that mean that I can only build one project within a folder?
Also doesn't that imply that if I wish to develop a second webpage, React has to be installed again ? Isn't it inefficient and memory consuming to install another hundreds of MB of node modules again?

Answer (score 2):

If the intention is to have 2 pages within a single site, you are likely looking for [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/) or some static site generator like [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/) or [Next](https://nextjs.org/).

If the intention is to create 2 independent websites, that have nothing to do one with another, then it's a good idea to make each of them have independent infrastructure  & dev. environment whatever memory-/resource-intensive those infrastructures are.